# Unexpected end of file while parsing object + AFNetworking

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, afnetworking, afnetworking-3

I have a valid JSON checked via http://jsonlint.com/ and http://json.parser.online.fr/

But i am unable to parse it and facing this error.

```
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Unexpected end of file while parsing object." 
UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Unexpected end of file while parsing object.}
```

I am using AFNetworking 3.0.Here is my code and JSON response via postman.

```
AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
[manager.requestSerializer setValue:apiKey forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];

[manager POST:urlString parameters:nil progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionTask *task, id responseObject){
    [self.delegate requestFinished:responseObject];

}failure:^(NSURLSessionTask *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"%@",error);
    [self.delegate requestFailed:[error localizedDescription]];
}];
```

[image: json response]

Please let me know if you have any idea whats going on here.Thanks

Comment: Found out the problem was with the json object.Working all fine now.